# Revert plaintext tag to html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm loading a special widget on web page that needs the content of the site to be hidden or not rendered (it's a layer over the site)

I'm hiding the content by wrapping the entire HTML with a "plaintext" tag and adding display:none to it.

There are times when i dont want my widget to load so i need to restore the content back, currently i'm doing it with a refresh of the page and a cookie that tells me not to wrap the content again.
I would like to avoid the refresh and just restore the content.
I tried to do it with a function that takes the content and removes it parent, but the HTML remains plaintext

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('plaintext');

while(b.length) {
    var parent = b[ 0 ].parentNode;
    while( b[ 0 ].firstChild ) {
        parent.insertBefore(  b[ 0 ].firstChild, b[ 0 ] );
    }
     parent.removeChild( b[ 0 ] );
}
```

Does anyone has any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Toggling display attribute doesn't work?

Comment: No, i edited my question, the name of the tag i'm using got deleted.
Toggling display does not effect it

Comment: why taking pain to add tag (which is not a valid tag) 'plaintext'. Keep that content inside an extra div, mark its id = 'plaintext'. And toggle its display property.

Comment: It is a valid tag, although it's deprecated.
The reason is that i don't want the hidden HTML to be rendered by the browser, i want the page to load as fast as possible

Comment: Toggling display will render the page? If yes then in both case toggling display and using plaintext needs rendering. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count = 0;
setInterval(redefine, 1000);
function redefine()
{
    img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    if(count++%2 ==0)
    img.style.display = 'none';
    else
    img.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

```css
img 
{
    width: 250px;
    height : 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://goo.gl/gxb9ij"/>
<p> This is working </p>
```

Is this what you are looking for? I am not refreshing the page instead just hiding details.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, the problem is not with the display style, it's with the fact that the HTML is now plain text because of the container tag